# Cannot find the list to remove an object

Tags: python, object, python-2.7

I have just started an exercise where I am supposed to complete a basic 'angrybirds' clone. 
I am stuck at the point where I want to remove an object from a list. The list contains all of the obstacles used in-game (boxes). 
So if I want to remove a box after it was hit I have to make a method to do that. This fails no matter how I do it.

```
class spel(object):
    def __init__(self):        
        self.obstacles = [obstacle(50,pos=(200,90)),]
  #defines all other stuff of the game

class obstacle(object):
    def __init__(self,size,pos):
   #defines how it looks like

    def break(self):
      #methode that defines what happens when the obstacles gets destroyed
        spel.obstacles.remove(self)
```

The error I get is:

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'obstacles'
```

After the last line.
Please excuse me for my noob-level, but the point is that I won't ever have to code again after this, so there is no need to explain everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined 'spel' as a class, not an object. Thus, you have received an error because Python is trying to find a member 'obstacles' of the spel class, which doesn't exist before the `__init__` method of individual spel objects is run.

To associate an object of the spel class with each individual obstacle you create, you could try giving objects of the obstacle class a data member that refers to their associated spel object. The data member can be instantiated in the obstacle class' `__init__` function. Like this:

```
class obstacle(object):
    def __init__(self, spel, size, pos):
        self.spel = spel
        #etc

    def break(self):
        self.spel.obstacles.remove(self)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: also don't use break as a method name, it's a reserved word

Comment: Thank you! @M4rtini I wrote the game in dutch, so it's 'breek'. I just quickly translated it for readability here...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't instantiated the spel class.

If you want to use a class like that, you have to intantiate( create an instance of) it.

Outside of a class like so:

```
app = spel() # app is an arbitrary name, could be anything
```

then you would call it's method like this:

```
app.obstacles.remove(self)
```

Or in you're case, from within another class:

```
self.spel = spel()

self.spel.obstacles.remove(self)
```

Comment: I know, I just didn't add all this to my post (sorry for being unclear)

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following:

```
class spel(object):
    obstacles = []
    def __init__(self,size,pos):        
        spel.obstacles.append(obstacle(size,pos))
        #defines all other stuff of the game

class obstacle(object):
    def __init__(self,size,pos):
        self.size = size
        self.pos = pos
    def brak(self):
        #methode that defines what happens when the obstacles gets destroyed
        spel.obstacles.remove(self)

from pprint import pprint

a = spel(50,(200,90))
pprint( spel.obstacles)
print

b = spel(5,(10,20))
pprint( spel.obstacles )
print

c = spel(3,None)
pprint( spel.obstacles )
print

spel.obstacles[0].brak()
pprint( spel.obstacles )
```

return

```
[<__main__.obstacle object at 0x011E0A30>]

[<__main__.obstacle object at 0x011E0A30>,
 <__main__.obstacle object at 0x011E0B30>]

[<__main__.obstacle object at 0x011E0A30>,
 <__main__.obstacle object at 0x011E0B30>,
 <__main__.obstacle object at 0x011E0AF0>]

[<__main__.obstacle object at 0x011E0B30>,
 <__main__.obstacle object at 0x011E0AF0>]
```

Comment: Thank you, but the solution @andreipmbcn gave me is what I am supposed to do. It is interesting however to see yours, as I didn't know you could place things before the " def__init__ "